# Install all xorg-edgers updates?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04, updates, xorg

I'm currently using ubuntu 13.04 and recently got a nvidia gpu. I've found that the easiest way for me to install the driver is to use the xorg-edgers ppa and it works really well.

However, I also get another bunch of updates from them including touchpad drivers, amd drivers, nouveau updates and some stuff i've not even heard of like buffer management and cirrus. Is it safe to install these updates? especially after installing the nvidia driver? I dont wana mess anything up.

If its not safe, is there a way to hide the updates?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 4):

As opposed to other answers to this question, the very PPA [states](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) that it should be used as a whole and NOT via individual packages (i.e. not pick individual updates, but install all of them).

> == Important notice ==
>
> This PPA is currently meant to be used as a whole. Please do *not* individually install packages from it, add it to your sources and let your package manager pull in every update. The packages here build against each other and compile different features based on whats available at build time. Do not assume that because it lets you install a DDX with just the driver and libdrm update that it will work. These packages are made with scripts that use the the current packages as the base, so some dependencies can be wrong and your package manager will not resolve that for you. If you want to individually install something from here, grab the source and rebuild it in your current environment instead.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu comes with program that installs proprietary drivers for you. look for it by writing proprietary into search-bar of your application menu. If your desktop does not have one, look for it in utilities.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Alternatively  consider downloading drivers from nvidia directly

you can add xorg-edgers if you want,but I don't recommend full update. update your system first and only then add their ppa.
their libraries are experimental often cause crushes.
In synaptic package manager try to install version which will not require xorg upgrade.
then remove ppa using synaptic) so updates wont install other stuff.

Comment: I do have the addition drivers section, but the drivers are old. I tried installing from nvidia but i always got opengl errors with steam. Xorg edgers is the only thing that has installed the drivers correctly with no errors. I always fully update before adding ppas, these extra updates come AFTER i install the ppa. Is it possible to add the ppa for xorg-edgers, install the nvidia driver, and then delete the ppa and keep the driver?

Comment: yes it is. the package manager will keep the oldest versioon and wont change it unles it has newer version
You can just untick the ppa in repo section of your package manager

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend you to install / download **all** the updates. Once I had done that in my notebook and at the next reboot my touchpad wasn't working anymore. I could only use the notebook with an external USB mouse. After I uninstalled `xorg-edgers` (that is, removed the PPA and all the packages that came along with it), my touchpad worked again. The uninstallation process wasn't actually so simple, I had to search a little bit the web to learn how to **completely** remove **all** the packages -- that is, only removing the PPA *is not* sufficient.

So, I recommend you to download **only what is really necessary**.

Comment: Well after i install ubuntu i install the updates it says. After that, i add the ppa, install the nvidia driver then reboot an everything works. After that, i THEN get a big list of more updates from xorg-edgers. So after I install the nvidia driver, should i remove the ppa so that i don't receive anymore updates from them? and the nvidia driver will stay intact ?

Comment: OK, so try the following. Install everything that you was prompted to. Reboot after that. See if everything is fine. If you don't notice any problem after that, then (apparently) it is OK so you can keep these upgrades. But if something strange happen (or if you suspect that), install the [ppa-purge PPA](https://launchpad.net/ppa-purge) then completely remove _xorg-edgers_ with `sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers` and update and upgrade your system again, then your original packages will be restored.

Answer (score 1):

Only install what you need from xorg-edgers and then disable the repository so that you do not accidentally update and break your system.