# Nvidia Drivers and Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I had Linux Mint installed on my desktop. I was using xserver to configure the cards and I could not for the life of me get my monitors to display properly. Here is some information on my setup:

I have a BFGTech GTS250 pushing to two 25" monitors.

I have another card GeForce GT 520 pushing to a 60" TV.

Out of the box ubuntu is doing quite well with both cards. Every now and then the mouse will freeze and the computer become unresponsive. It will suddenly catch up with all my mouse movement and I am ready to rock.

I have attempted the following:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current
```

reboot.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

reboot.

Now, my large TV is displaying a blank screen and the mouse is a large "X". Any advice? Thanks in advance for any help.

After removing the nvidia install and installing from nvidia-331 I get the same results. Here is my xorg.conf:

http://pastebin.com/93JtX5Ge

Comment: The big X sounds like the card is running in low-graphics mode. Have you tried the edgers PPA?

Comment: I am not. This is the first time I am hearing of this.

Comment: I would roll back to the previous drivers, then investigate using the edgers PPA - check out [this discussion](http://askubuntu.com/questions/302930/install-all-xorg-edgers-updates) for some issues with using it. And if you haven't already, read the [Wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) regarding Nvidia drivers. Just went through a bunch of pain myself getting drivers working on an old 300M card.

Comment: I installed nvidia-331 from the repo and uninstalled the drive provided by nvidia. Still yielding the same results (Blank screen on my GT520). I have added my xorg.conf file - I was told it may be something with my BusID but both seem to check out with lspci.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo ppa-purge ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

Your solution.

Comment: Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: bumblebee stable

Comment: Try:

sudo apt-get --purge remove bumblebee

Comment: I'm not sure how this resolves the problem?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/400010/251432

Comment: I attempted this with no luck. 

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2210394